# How to insert a Symbol (Pound, Euro, Copyright) into a Textbox

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, symbols

I can use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> Key with the Number Pad to type symbols, but how do I programmatically insert a Symbol (Pound, Euro, Copyright) into a Textbox?

I have a configuration screen so I need to dynamically create the \uXXXX's.

[image]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In C#, the Unicode character literal `\uXXXX` where the `X`'s are hex characters will let you specify Unicode characters. For example:

- `\u00A3` is the Pound sign, £.
- `\u20AC` is the Euro sign, €.
- `\u00A9` is the copyright symbol, ©.

You can use these Unicode character literals just like any other character in a string.

For example, `"15 \u00A3 per item"` would be the string "15 £ per item".

You can put such a string in a textbox just like you would with any other string.

**Note:** You can also just copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) a symbol off of a website, like [Wikipedia (Pound sign)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_sign), and then paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) it directly into a string literal in your C# source code file. C# source code files use Unicode natively. This approach completely relieves you from ever even having to know the four hex digits for the symbol you want.

To parallel the example above, you could make the same string literal as simply `"15 £ per item"`.

**Edit:** If you want to *dynamically* create the Unicode character from its hex string, you can use this:

```
public static char HexToChar(string hex)
{
    return (char)ushort.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
}
```

For example, `HexToChar("20AC")` will get you the Euro sign.

If you want to do the opposite operation dynamically:

```
public static string CharToHex(char c)
{
    return ((ushort)c).ToString("X4");
}
```

For example `CharToHex('€')` will get you `"20AC"`.

The choice of `ushort` corresponds to the range of possible `char` values, shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: Let me try this. Nah, I need to dynamically create it **\uXXXX**. When I try this: `symbolSyntax = "\u" + symbolSyntax` it needs me to escape the \u

Comment: @JeremyThompson Do you really want to create the character from the symbol hex dynamically like that? If so I can update the answer to include that as well.

Comment: @JeremyThompson - Dynamically creating symbols from hex wasn't asked in the question, if that's what you want be more clear next time.

Comment: I don't have time to test, but try:  (Char)Convert.ToInt32("20AC",16)

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I'm sure this will help others in the future

Answer (score 11):

I cant believe this was difficult to find on the internet!

For future developers,if you have the unicode character its easy to do. eg:

**C#:**

```
var selectionIndex = txt.SelectionStart;

string copyrightUnicode = "00A9";
int value = int.Parse(copyrightUnicode, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
string symbol = char.ConvertFromUtf32(value).ToString();

txt.Text = txt.Text.Insert(selectionIndex, symbol);
txt.SelectionStart = selectionIndex + symbol.Length;
```

**VB.Net**

```
Dim selectionIndex = txt.SelectionStart

Dim copyrightUnicode As String = "00A9"
Dim value As Integer = Integer.Parse(copyrightUnicode, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
Dim symbol As String = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(value).ToString()

txt.Text = txt.Text.Insert(selectionIndex, symbol)
txt.SelectionStart = selectionIndex + symbol.Length
```