# C# Decimal.Parse and invalid input string

Tags: c#, string, parsing, decimal

I'm having problems with error: input string was not in a correct format. I'm trying to convert curency in datagrid. At point where I get error (this is where I set value to value variable) text variable haves value 22.22 so I don't know what is wrong with format.

```
public void valute()
{
    int rowCount = dataGridView1.RowCount;
    decimal value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        string text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

        if (evro_check.Checked)
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = text + " €";
        else if (dolar_check.Checked)
        {
            value = Decimal.Parse(text.Replace(',', '.'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = value.ToString() + " $";
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = value + " £";
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Right now I'm just adding curency sign and later I'll also change € to $ and thats way I'm using additional variable (value) and not using text for other 2 currencys.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any spaces or anything similar in the string? Also note that your title talks about `Double.Parse`, but your code uses `Decimal.Parse`...

Comment: If you are going to place the value in grid's cell as text, why do you convert it to the decimal in the first place?

Comment: Just use `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = text + " $"`

Comment: I need to convert it to decimal because I'll need to multiplay it with currency exchanges.

Comment: What is the value of `text` exactly? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: also try with tryparse instead of parse method

Comment: I'm guessing since you are iterating over all rows, maybe you have an empty cell. Decimal.Parse on empty string throws an error if I remember correctly.

Comment: @KcDoD - Empty throws System.FormatException: No Digits found. See example https://ideone.com/wrDJSs

Comment: @jornare I was running an example with tryparse [with out value initialized to 0 :D ], so my mad have removed that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option you have is to use `Tryparse` over `Parse`

[TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This overload differs from the Decimal.Parse(String) method by returning a Boolean value that indicates whether the parse operation succeeded instead of returning the parsed numeric value. It eliminates the need to use exception handling to test for a FormatException in the event that s is invalid and cannot be successfully parsed.

A suggestion to improve the code

```
string text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
Decimal value=0;

if (Decimal.TryParse(text.Replace(',', '.'), out value))
{
   //parse success
   dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = value.ToString() + " $"; // put the correct value
}
else {
   //parse not success 
   dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value ="- $"; // Put something which allow you to identify the issue.
 }
```

This will allow you to identify where you have wrongly formatted values in data grid.

Comment: Yeah, tryparse helped me to identify where I went wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Seriously? Suggesting to debug your application via screen output is a terrible answer! Why wouldn't you just put a breakpoint into the line where it failed to debug the cause? This is completely backwards! VisualStudio has probably the best debugger in the industry and you decided to abandon it????

Comment: @dustinmoris Are you high or what :D  ?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with cultures.
For example in the UK this "10,000.10" is 10 thousand and 1/10 of your currency, while in Germany the format would be the other way around: "10.000,10".

What you do is replacing all "," with an ".". Unless you changed the current culture of your application to a format where this makes sense, then this will obviously end up with a FormatException.

You should set the CultureInfo to the culture which you are targeting.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b28bx3bh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Also, it would be better to use a format provider, which will format you a correct monetary string according to the specified culture:

```
decimal value = 10000;

value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// Output : ¤10,000.00

value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"));
// Output : 10.000,00 €

value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")).Dump();
// Output: $10,000.00
```

If you notice, the American format puts the currency symbol at the front, and the German one is at the end. You didn't account for any of these things either.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b22a4x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void valute()
{
    int rowCount = dataGridView1.RowCount;
    decimal value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        string text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

        if (evro_check.Checked)
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = text + " €";
        else if (dolar_check.Checked)
        {
            if (text != "" || text != "&nbsp;")
            {
                value = Decimal.Parse(text.Replace(',', '.'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = value.ToString() + " $";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = value + " £";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Culture Info class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
  public void valute()
  {
   int rowCount = dataGridView1.RowCount;
   decimal value = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
   {
       string text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

       if (evro_check.Checked)
           dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = text.ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr")); //€
       else if (dolar_check.Checked)
       {
           value = Decimal.Parse(text.Replace(',', '.'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
           dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = text.ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-CA")); //$
       }
       else
       {
           dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = text.ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"));
       }
   }
  }
```

**Second Approach**
make use of Unicode

```
public static char HexToChar(string hex)
{
  return (char)ushort.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
}
```

\u00A3 is the Pound sign, £

\u20AC is the Euro sign, €.

\u0024 is the dollar sign, $.

[How to insert a Symbol (Pound, Euro, Copyright) into a Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627694/how-to-insert-a-symbol-pound-euro-copyright-into-a-textbox)